# @media адаптация под различные браузеры

Tags: css

Я пытаюсь выравнять кнопки в сетке интернет магазина (product-loop), и столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Одни и те же координаты в фаерфоксе и хроме отображаются по разному,  при одних и тех же координатах кнопка отображается в разных браузерах со значительным смещением.

Подскажите решение этой проблемы.

Мой код:

```
.compare 
{

 width: 70px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 20px;
 padding: 0 10px !important;
 padding-right: 20px !important;
 padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px), only screen and (max-device- 
width: 1920px) {
.compare 
{
 position: absolute;          /* или  position: relative;*/
 right: -500px;
 top: -720px;

 }

 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (max-device- 
 width: 1024px) {
 .compare 
 {

 position: absolute;             /* или  position: relative;*/
 right: -300px;
 top: 700px;

 }

 }
```

Comment: Покажите html-код и вообще составьте [mcve]

Comment: Вот страница sport-print.online/sample-page , кнопка "сравнить", при разрешении 1920 на 1080 на хроме и гугле отображается с большим смещением.

Comment: Не ссылку, а текстом прямо в вопросе

Comment: =))) если в яйцах нету мочи не поможет вам и сочи!

Answer (score 1):

Ответ кроется в самих брузерах.

По умолчанию разные элементы выглядят по разному в зависимости от браузера.
Почитайте про `normalize.css` и `reset.css`

- Первый приводит к тому что все элементы во всех браузерах выглядят
  одинаково
- Второй к тому что все сбрасывается на минимум  и вы сами
  устанавливаете нужные параметры.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что это относится к данному вопросу? Возможно, в html-коде используется только div — а уж div'ы отображаются одинаково в любых браузерах без всяких normalize/reset

Comment: Hardcore Gamer сказал что одни и те же координаты имеют разное значение, во всех браузерах разное значение `margin` и `padding` как минимум.

Comment: Это вы попытались угадать, а возможно на самом деле проблема не в этом. Примера, который продемонстрировал бы влияние именно браузерных margin/padding, поблизости не видно

Comment: Вот страница https://sport-print.online/sample-page/ , кнопка "сравнить", при разрешении 1920 на 1080 на хроме и гугле отображается с большим смещением.

Comment: Применение normalize.css и reset.css приводит к сбросу места положения кнопки на дефолтные, после чего место положение нельзя редактировать. Есть ли еще какие нибудь идеи?

Comment: Но вообще normalize.css и reset.css классные штуки), не знал раньше благодарю =)

Comment: rafnsvartr огромное спасибо за твой ответ!